# Multithreaded implementation of K-means clustering algorithm in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, machine-learning, clustering

Hello I have written a multi-threaded implementation of the K-means clustering algorithm. The main goals are correctness and scalable performance on multi-core CPUs. I expect to code to not have race conditions and no data races, and to scale good with more CPU cores.

```
package bg.unisofia.fmi.rsa;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ParallelKmeans {

    private static CountDownLatch countDownLatch;
    private final int n;
    private final int k;
    public int numThreads = 1;
    List<Node> observations = new ArrayList<>();
    float[][] clusters;

    public ParallelKmeans(int n, int k) {
        this.n = n;
        this.k = k;
        clusters = new float[k][n];
        for (float[] cluster : clusters) {
            for (int i = 0; i < cluster.length; i++) {
                cluster[i] = (float) Math.random();
            }
        }
    }

    public void assignStep(ExecutorService executorService) throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable[] assignWorkers = new AssignWorker[numThreads];
        final int chunk = observations.size() / assignWorkers.length;
        countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(numThreads);
        for (int j = 0; j < assignWorkers.length; j++) {
            assignWorkers[j] = new AssignWorker(j * chunk, (j + 1) * chunk);
            executorService.execute(assignWorkers[j]);
        }
        countDownLatch.await();

    }

    public void updateStep(ExecutorService executorService) throws InterruptedException {

        countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(numThreads);

        UpdateWorker[] updateWorkers = new UpdateWorker[numThreads];
        final int chunk = observations.size() / updateWorkers.length;
        for (int j = 0; j < updateWorkers.length; j++) {
            updateWorkers[j] = new UpdateWorker(j * chunk, (j + 1) * chunk);
            executorService.execute(updateWorkers[j]);
        }
        countDownLatch.await();
        clusters = new float[k][n];
        int[] counts = new int[k];

        for (UpdateWorker u : updateWorkers) {
            VectorMath.add(counts, u.getCounts());
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                VectorMath.add(clusters[j], u.getClusters()[j]);
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < clusters.length; j++) {
            if (counts[j] != 0) {
                VectorMath.divide(clusters[j], counts[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    void cluster() throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            assignStep(executorService);
            updateStep(executorService);
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    public static class Node {
        float[] vec;
        int cluster;
    }

    class AssignWorker implements Runnable {
        int l, r;

        public AssignWorker(int l, int r) {
            this.l = l;
            this.r = r;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<Node> chunk = observations.subList(l, r);
            for (Node ob : chunk) {
                float minDist = Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
                int idx = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < clusters.length; i++) {
                    if (minDist > VectorMath.dist(ob.vec, clusters[i])) {
                        minDist = VectorMath.dist(ob.vec, clusters[i]);
                        idx = i;
                    }
                }
                ob.cluster = idx;
            }
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    }

    class UpdateWorker implements Runnable {
        int[] counts;
        int l, r;
        float[][] clusters;

        UpdateWorker(int l, int r) {
            this.l = l;
            this.r = r;
        }

        int[] getCounts() {
            return counts;
        }

        public float[][] getClusters() {
            return clusters;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            this.counts = new int[k];
            this.clusters = new float[k][n];
            for (Node ob : observations.subList(l, r)) {
                VectorMath.add(this.clusters[ob.cluster], ob.vec);
                this.counts[ob.cluster]++;
            }
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This code does nothing. `observations` never gets assigned any values.

Comment: Unless you're assigning it from outside this class before running it, in which case the calling context would be necessary to figure out if it works.

Comment: Of course they are set from otuside. I dont see how tht is relevant to the things I care about. I found my own mistake anyway. I need to use volatile keyword.

Comment: please post `VectorMath` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Interface

Your classes interface is confusing.  You have an internal method `cluster`, which appears to be the main entry point into your `ParallelKmeans` class.  However, it then calls two public methods (`assignStep` and `updateStep`) that do the actual work.  This seems wrong.  Particularly since `assignStep` and `updateStep` can't be run safely at the same time.

## countDownLatch

You're using a static `CoundDownLatch`, which you're recreating in your `assignStep` and `updateStep` methods.  This doesn't really make sense to me.  By having it static, you're having it shared across all instances of `ParallelKmeans` classes.  Is this really the expected behaviour?  As you're reinitialising the static in both of your public methods, it creates the possibility of it being changed unexpectedly.  If you want to stay with a `CountDownLatch`, consider making it a local variable to each of your public methods and passing it into the constructors for your workers so that they have access to it.

## How many threads

You're creating a threadpool that's based around the number of processors the machine has.  However, both your update/assign steps are using the member variable `numThreads`, which is hard coded to 1.  This disconnect is strange.  Consider changing your startup code to calculate how many threads you want to use, then perform construction and assignment using this number.

Comment: I agree about the static thing. It makes absolutely no sense for the latch to be static.

Comment: Also agree on the last point. Can you elaborate on the first "Interface" one though?

Comment: @TeodorDyakov When I look at a new class, I start by looking at the methods with a public scope.  These are advertising that they are the way a class is expected to be interacted with.  I think of this as the 'public interface'. For your class, the public methods look like they aren't designed to be called by a client.  The next thing I'll look at is the methods with no defined scope, i.e. package-local visibility.  These usually offer a bit more control because there's assumed knowledge from other code in the package, the 'internal interface'.

Comment: @TeodorDyakov in your code, `cluster` seems like it should be public, whereas `assignStep` and `updateStep` seems like they should be at least package-local, or more probably private.

Answer (score 0):

I have local variables in the `UpdateWorker` class that are later accessed from the main Thread. Unless I mark these variables as `volatile` there may be visibility issues.
The same thing also applies to the `cluster` field in `Observation`